# Combined scatter and line ggplot with proper legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to find a clear approach for combined scatter and line plots with `ggplot2` that have an appropriate legend. The following works, in principle, but with warnings:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

## 2 data sets, one for the lines, one for the points
tbl <- tibble(
  f = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10),
  x = rep(1:10, 2),
  y = c(1e-4 * exp(1:10), log(1:10))
)

obs <- tibble(
  f = rep("c", 5),
  x = seq(2, 10, 2),
  y = log(seq(2, 10, 2)) + rnorm(5, sd = 0.1)
)

rbind(tbl, obs)  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = f, linetype = f)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(show.legend = TRUE, aes(shape = f), size = 3) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "blank")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(NA, NA, 16))
```

but I would like to get rid of warnings and to write something like:

```
scale_shape_manual(values=c("none", "none", "circle"))
```

Is there already a "none" or "empty" shape code? Several past answers have been suggested on SO, but I wonder if there is a recent canonical way.

Comment: You can eliminate the warnings by using the `na.rm` argument in `geom_points`: `geom_point(show.legend = TRUE, aes(shape = f), size = 3, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Whow, great! Not obvious, but completely plausible at the second look. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!